FastAPI Starlette Middleware session - unable to access session data after redirect
I'm writing a simple web app using Fast API as the backend, and I want authentication to be achieved via Azure B2C. The logic of this all is not really important now, I just want to be able to test that I can successfully log in using different methods.
But, after trying for quite a long time, I cannot figure out, why I can't retrieve users's data from sessions after redirecting.
import logging
import secrets

from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, HTTPException, status
from fastapi.responses import RedirectResponse, JSONResponse
from starlette.middleware.sessions import SessionMiddleware

from datetime import datetime
import jwt
import time
import json

from logger import logger
from env import *
from db_helpers import *
from mailer import *
from ad_helpers import *
from models import CreateUserRequest, InviteUserRequest, AcceptInvitationRequest, ProcessGoogleTokenRequest, ResendInvitationRequest, UserResponse, CreateUserResponse, InviteUserResponse

# Logging
app = FastAPI()
app.add_middleware(SessionMiddleware, secret_key="your-very-secret-key", max_age=None)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

logger.debug(f"B2C Authority: {B2C_AUTHORITY}")

# Middleware to handle session cookies
@app.middleware("http")
async def session_middleware(request: Request, call_next):
    response = await call_next(request)
    session = request.cookies.get('session')
    if session:
        response.set_cookie(key='session', value=session, httponly=True)
    return response

# FRONT ROUTES

@app.get('/login')
async def login(request: Request):
    """
    Get the authorization URL for login.
    """
    logger.debug("Executing login function")
    auth_url = build_auth_url()
    logger.debug(f"Authorization URL: {auth_url}")
    return JSONResponse(content={"auth_url": auth_url})

@app.get('/oauth_callback')
async def oauth_callback(request: Request):
    """
    Handle the OAuth2 authorization code and store user information in the session.
    """
    if 'code' in request.query_params:
        logger.debug("Authorization code received: %s", request.query_params['code'])
        cache = load_cache(request)
        try:
            result = build_msal_app(cache=cache).acquire_token_by_authorization_code(
                request.query_params['code'],
                scopes=[],
                redirect_uri=f"{BASE_URL}/oauth_callback")  # Ensure proper URL
            logger.debug(f"Token acquisition result: {result}")
            if 'error' in result:
                logger.error("Error in token acquisition: %s", result['error_description'])
                raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail=f"Error: {result['error_description']}")
            user_info = result.get('id_token_claims')
            request.session['user'] = user_info
            save_cache(request, cache)
            logger.debug("Session data saved: %s", request.session['user'])
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error("Exception during token acquisition: %s", str(e))
            raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(e))
        return RedirectResponse("/user-profile")

    if not request.session.get('user'):
        logger.debug("No user session found, redirecting to login")
        return RedirectResponse("/login/")
    logger.debug("User session found, redirecting to profile")
    return RedirectResponse("/user-profile")

@app.get('/user-profile', response_model=UserResponse)
async def user_profile(request: Request):
    """
    Get the user's profile information from the session.
    """
    user = request.session.get('user')
    logger.debug("user data from session: %s", user)
    if not user:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="User not logged in")

    return UserResponse(message="User profile retrieved successfully", email=user['emails'][0], id=user['oid'])

I will be very glad for your help or any hints ON what I should even look at.
I tried to set and retrieve THEuser's data from THEsession, but it shows None all the time.

How are you trying to use the session? Since you're using the Starlette session middleware, there shouldn't be any need to set or read cookies yourself.

I need to save the user's data obtained from Azure authentication endpoint in the form of a token into session to be able to access it on different endpoints.

Yes, but that's not what I'm asking - how are you trying to read the value, and what doesn't work? There is no indication of you reading or setting a value that's accessible to the endpoints - you can work with request.session directly.
